# Extract variable from 2 different files correspondingly using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to extract variable from 2 different files correspondingly.

Meaning that if fileA have these values

```
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
```

And fileB have

```
A
B
C
```

It should come out as:

```
FIRST, A
SECOND, B
THIRD, C
```

Here's what I coded so far:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%FileA%) do (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%FileB%) do (
    echo %%i, %%a
  )
)
```

But it will not match correctly, meaning it will be:

```
FIRST, A
FIRST, B
FIRST, C
SECOND, A
SECOND, B
SECOND, C
THIRD, A
THIRD, B
THIRD, C
```

Comment: Simple, fast, and robust solution using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) - `jrepl "$" "$txt=', '+stdin.ReadLine()" /jq /f "fileA.txt" <"fileB.txt"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read two text files simultaneously when you read one by the `for /F` loop and the other one by `set /P` and [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< "fileB.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("fileA.txt") do (
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        echo(%%L, !LINE!
    )
)
endlocal
```

For the above code to work, the following restrictions apply:

- the text files must be ASCII/ANSI text files, not Unicode;
- the text files must contain Windows-style line-breaks (carriage-return plus line-feed);
- file `fileA.txt` must not contain lines longer than about 8190 bytes/characters;
- file `fileB.txt` must not contain lines longer than about 1021 bytes/characters;
- the text files are expected to contain the same number of lines; actually, `fileA.txt` defines how many lines are read from both files, so there might be lines of `fileB.txt` ignored if it contains more, or empty ones may be assumed if it contains less than `fileA.txt`;
- `fileA.txt` should not contain empty lines, because such are ignored by `for /F`;
- `fileA.txt` should not contain lines beginning with `;`, because such are ignored by `for /F` due to its default `eol` option;
- `fileA.txt` should not contain `!` as such may be lost or lead to unexpected results, because delayed variable expansion is enabled during expansion of the `for /F` variable reference `%%L`;

---

To overcome the last three of the aforementioned limitations, you can use the following code:

```cmd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
< "fileB.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "fileA.txt"') do (
        set "LINEA=%%L"
        set "LINEB=" & set /P LINEB=""
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINEA:*:=!, !LINEB!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

Here is how it works:

- `findstr /N` precedes every matching line with a line number and a `:` and search string `^` matches all lines, so no line of `fileA.txt` appears empty to `for /F` any more, so such lines are no longer ignored by `for /F`;
- said line number prefix avoids `;` to appear as the first character, so lines of `fileA.txt` beginning with that character are no longer ignored by `for /F`;
- since delayed variable expansion is no longer enabled during expansion of the `for /F` variable reference `%%L` but only when actually needed, lines containing `!` are no problem any more;

Comment: This is a really neat solution I haven't seen before. Why does the extra pair of parenthesis will make it so that for each for-loop iteration the next line in `fileB.txt` is parsed to the stdin stream of the `set /p` command instead of parsing just the first line of `fileB.txt` every single time?

Comment: @treintje, the additional pair of parentheses ensures that the entire `for` loop is input-redirected, so the file `fileB.txt` is opened once, then each `set /P` command reads a single line; if you omit the parentheaes, you actually redirect the body of the loop, so the file is reopened for every loop iteration, so the file pointer becomes reset, hence you read the first line of `fileB.txt` each time...

Comment: Note that there are a number of situations where this code (as currently written) can fail. For example, `!` within fileA, or any line within fileA that begins with `;`, or fileA line longer than ~8k chars, or fileB line longer than 1021 chars, or fileB line that does not end with carriage return, linefeed... Some of the limitations can be fixed with pure batch. Others are inherent to batch programming.

Comment: I am aware of these limitations, @dbenham; the purpose of my answer is to demonstrate the principle of how to read files simultaneously and to cover the provided sample data; if the OP needs to work around some limitations, they should comment here, or even better, ask a new question; anyway, I am going to update my answer to be complete...

Comment: @dbenham, I updated my answer now as promised and implemented a work-around for some of the said restrictions...

Comment: I know you are well aware of the limitations. But I'm pretty sure the OP (and many other readers) are not. My comment was for their benefit.